# Why not working my time.sleep(x) code in python on debian?

Tags: python, selenium, time, web-scraping, sleep

I want to web-scraping a lot of pages from an API website, so i have to wait to load the elements and after my script can click on them. But the time.sleep(5) is not working, because it is jumping instatly to the next page.

What am I wrong?

My code:

```
def scrape(urls):
    browser = webdriver.Firefox()
    datatable=[]
    for url in urls:
        browser.get(url)
        time.sleep(5)
        driver.find_element_by_xpath('//button[contains(text(), "Load earlier flights")]').click()
        time.sleep(5)
        html = browser.page_source
        soup=BeautifulSoup(html,"html.parser")
        table = soup.find('table', { "class" : "table table-condensed table-hover data-table m-n-t-15" })
        soup2=BeautifulSoup(html,"html.parser")
        name = soup2.h2.string
        soup3=BeautifulSoup(html,"html.parser")
        name2 = soup3.h1.string
        soup4=BeautifulSoup(html,"html.parser")
        name3 = soup4.h3.string
        name4 = datetime.now()

        for record in table.find_all('tr', class_="hidden-xs hidden-sm ng-scope"):
            temp_data = []
            temp_data.append(name4)
            temp_data.append(name)
            temp_data.append(name2)    
            temp_data.append(name3)    
            for data in record.find_all("td"):
                temp_data.append(data.text.encode('latin-1'))
            newlist = filter(None, temp_data)
            datatable.append(newlist)

    time.sleep(10) 
    browser.close()
    return datatable
```

The first URL:  flightradar24.com/data/airports/ams/arrivals

Comment: why do you create **4** soups having the same content (hint, you need not!)

Comment: Relying on `time.sleep()` to wait for a page to be fully loaded is brittle at best. You may want to check whether there's some better solution in selenium...

Comment: I know there is a better solution like wait elements, etc, but im interested in that why time.sleep() is not working in my code.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `time.sleep`, use the explicit and implicit waits provided by [selenium](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html).

Comment: And here in my code i have to use it?
"driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.implicitly_wait(10) 
driver.get("url")
myDynamicElement = driver.find_element_by_name("Load earlier flight")"

?

Comment: @Mr.D if you want a implicit wait, yes. But you can optimize your code and use an explicit wait.

Answer (score 0):

I would use the "expected_conditions" that come with selenium.

for example.

```
        from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

        Def someFunc(self): 
          self.myDriver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="webDrivers\chromedriver.exe")
          self.waitElement = WebDriverWait(self.myDriver,10) 
          self.waitElement.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CLASS_NAME,'page-link')))
          #do something with page
```

This would wait 10 sec for all the class names "page-link" that are located by selenium.
You can find out more info [Here](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_support/selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.html)